# PHP Array formatting to change brackets to quotes

Tags: php, arrays, formatting

```
<?php
$dataArray=array();  
//get data from database
$sql="SELECT MONTHNAME(date) as month, DAY(date) as day, YEAR(date) as year, date, AVG(score) as score FROM post_appt_survey WHERE date BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 YEAR) AND NOW() GROUP BY MONTH(date) order by YEAR(date) asc, MONTH(date) asc";
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
if ($result) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $day=$row["day"];
      $date=$row["date"];
      $month=$row["month"];
      $year=$row["year"];
      $score=$row["score"];
      //add to data array
      $dataArray[$month.' '.$year]=$score;

  }
}
print_r($dataArray, false);
?>
```

My output reads as

Array ( [August 2013] => 9.3333 [September 2013] => 10.0000 [October 2013] => 7.0000 [November 2013] => 8.5000 [December 2013] => 8.7500 [January 2014] => 6.3333 )

I need it to read as

Array ( "August 2013" => 9.3333 "September 2013" => 10.0000 "October 2013" => 7.0000 "November 2013" => 8.5000 "December 2013" => 8.7500 "January 2014" => 6.3333 )

PLEASE HELP

Comment: that is what the standard print_r function returns. If you want to display it differently then you need to manually iterate through the $dataArray array and display it in a format that you like.

Comment: try using foreach ($dataArray as $key => $val){echo $key ."=>" . $val; } for example.

Answer (score 0):

If there are no other square brackets in the output (which seems so) try:

```
$output = print_r($dataArray, true);
$output = str_replace(array('[', ']'), '"', $output);
echo $output;
```